# Why setting src of img by jquery in Django does not have to include {{MEDIA_URL}}

Tags: jquery, django

Just a curious question.
In order to display an image where the image is in {{MEDIA_URL}}, we need to do like this in Django:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}} + file-url ">
```

With Jquery, you don't have to include {{MEDIA_URL}}:

```
$('.myImg').attr('src',"file-url");
```

Why?

Comment: This is not true, You would have to do the same in both the cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because django don't parse .js files. To include media_url in js files you should do in your base template in head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mediaUrl = '{{ MEDIA_URL }}';
</script>
```

Then you can use this in your scripts:

```
$('.myImg').attr('src', mediaUrl + file-url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would still have to do:

```
$('.myImg').attr('src','{{MEDIA_URL}}'+file_url);
```